unable to change default chroma collection name [SpringAiCollection]
Problem with Changing Default Chroma Collection Name in Spring AI
I am unable to change the default Chroma collection name in my Spring AI application.
I am trying to use the following property:
spring.ai.vectorstore.chroma.collection-name=embeddings_db

However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. The application still uses the default collection name: SpringAiCollection.
What I've Tried

Verified the property is correctly set in the application configuration.
Restarted the application after making changes.

Expected Behavior
The application should use the custom collection name embeddings_db, but it continues to use the default name.
Environment

Spring Boot starter parent version: 3.3.1
Spring AI Version: 1.0.0-M1
Java Version: openjdk-22 Oracle OpenJDK 22.0.1 - aarch64
Chroma started in docker: chromadb/chroma:latest (0.5.4)

Question
How can I successfully change the default Chroma collection name to embeddings_db?
Any help would be appreciated!

The property key changed between 1.0.0-M1 and 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
You need to insert "store" between "chroma" and "collection-name"
Find details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ai/reference/1.0/api/vectordbs/chroma.html
